# Div elements not showing up after CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

New to web development, and I am creating a new website, currently using html, js, and css but some elements are missing after applying css?.
The two div elements box1 and box2 are missing with everything in it. I opened up the inspect option in chrome and saw that they were in the code but not loaded up?

```
<header>
  <img src="SAGE LOGO.png">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="box1">
    <label class="ld-label">
            Project Number:
          </label>
    <input class="ld-url-input" type="text" id="fetchURL" />
    <button type="button" id="add" class="design_button add">Draw</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <form method="post" action="data.php">
      <label class="ld-label">
                  Add Project:
                </label>
      <input class="ld-url-input" type="text" name="textdata">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</main>

<div id="super">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header img {
  height: 80px;
}

body {
  height: 125vh;
  background-color: #222641;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

main {
  color: white;
}

header {
  background-color: #A80B16;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
}

.ld-label {
  width: 200px;
}

.ld-url-input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `header` is overlapping with your content.

Either remove `position: fixed;` for `header` or give `padding-top: 80px;` for your `main`

```css
header img {
  height: 80px;
}

body {
  background-color: #222641;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

main {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

header {
  background-color: #A80B16;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
}

.ld-label {
  width: 200px;
}

.ld-url-input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="SAGE LOGO.png">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="box1">
    <label class="ld-label">
        Project Number:
      </label>
    <input class="ld-url-input" type="text" id="fetchURL" />
    <button type="button" id="add" class="design_button add">Draw</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <form method="post" action="data.php">
      <label class="ld-label">
              Add Project:
            </label>
      <input class="ld-url-input" type="text" name="textdata">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</main>

<div id="super">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: yes, it's silly. Either accept the answer or feel free to remove the post.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Fixed Position of header box1 and box2 are move behind header as fixed position division will not take it's space so to resolve it please put below css in main element..

```css
main{
    margin-top: 82px;
    padding: 20px;
    }
```